# Incorrect & Correct statement

Tags: javascript, html

I need help to finish my incorrect & correct statement.
It shows both incorrect and correct every time I answer the question.

```js
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  let useAnswer = document.querySelector('input').value.toLowerCase()
  if (useAnswer === currentClue.answer.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log('correct')
  } else {
    console.log('incorrect')
  }

});
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="question"></div>
  <input id="answer_input" type="answer" placeholder="Enter Answer" required/>
  <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="result">
  <p class="result_success">Correct</p>
  <p class="result_fail">Incorrect</p>
  <p class="result_correct-answer"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: just put a `return` after the answer

Comment: Please define variable to help you i can got submit button but I can't got `currentClue.answer`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the event listener to listen for the submit event (you already had the `event.preventDefault()` that prevent the submit of the form) on the form. I gave both the form and input element a name.

```js
var currentClue = {answer: "Test"};

document.forms.form01.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let useAnswer = event.target.answer_input.value.toLowerCase();
  if (useAnswer === currentClue.answer.toLowerCase()) {
    console.log('correct');
  } else {
    console.log('incorrect');
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <div id="question"></div>
  <input id="answer_input" name="answer_input" type="answer" placeholder="Enter Answer" required/>
  <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<div class="result">
  <p class="result_success">Correct</p>
  <p class="result_fail">Incorrect</p>
  <p class="result_correct-answer"></p>
</div>
```